# FOSUserBundle Adding REST Parameters or better way?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a Symfony 2 project which uses FOSUserBundle for user management. My web app currently has a simple system which allows private groups. I am adding the ability to send email invites to my web app based on the user emails which are entered by a group owner in my web app.

The system works pretty well, but a problem occurs when a new user registers an account and doesn't use the same email address the group owner supplied. This usually requires me to jump into the system and manually add the users to the group (about 2 dozen cases spring up for every 200 users).

I would like to add an invite url in the new email notifications I will be adding. I would like to modify the register route to something along these lines:
/register/{email address}
And then update my register_content.html.twig template to populate the email field.

I'm not sure what the simplest way to do this is. I started looking at making a copy of the controller and passing my parameter through that way, but it looked like that might not be as good creating a new event listener.

My Googling did not turn up anything helpful. I'm hoping someone could point me towards the ideal way to handle this?

Thanks!

Comment: Just curious, why are you letting them change their email address after the invite was already sent?

Comment: @JasonRoman The invite is currently only being created in the web app. If that email doesn't correspond to a user record, then I am going to send an email with the above URL to create a new account.

Comment: Why not create a table that stores invitations with a randomly-generated hash that also stores the email address.  That way if the user clicks the invitation w/the hash they don't have to even enter their email address because you'll already have it stored?  Or is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: @JasonRoman I could do that. But I would still need to pass the hash through the URL and I find myself wondering what the best way for modifying the URL for this new piece of data is (with respect to FOSUserBundle best practices)

Comment: How about you create the registration form like normal but remove the `username/email` field, then when the form is submitted, you fetch it from the database invite table (via the hash) and set it there?

Comment: @JasonRoman I like your idea but it's still not clear to me how I am delivering the hash to the user. The user receives an invite email with a url: let's say http://www.example.com/register/{hashid} . What is the best way to handle this in FOSUserBundle? Should I create a new route and then make a copy of the RegistrationController or should I create an event to listen to initialize on the Registration Form or is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: You could override the RegistrationController and any others you need as their documentation shows here: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.md and add the functionality there.

Comment: @JasonRoman thanks for the comments. I decided to just handle this is the client as it is less invasive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to just parse the email in Jquery and populate the email input box. I found this to be less invasive than creating a custom copy of the Registration controller.